# How do I send [only] the shift key in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, shift

Is there a way to send just the shift key (not in combination with another key) in Javascript?

I know I can ***detect*** the shift key with `evt.shiftKey`, but how do I ***send*** only the shift key?

I have tried:

```
$.event.trigger({type:'keypress', which : character.charCodeAt(16) });
```

My console.log gives me: `Uncaught ReferenceError: character is not defined`

Comment: The only reason I can think you'd want to do this is for something malicious. What's your goal?

Comment: My goal is to send the shift key to `datatables` plug-in, in the search criteria; I have found that it only updates after a second keyup event.  The shift key will not affect the search criteria.

Comment: Your comment tells me you are having the XY problem here.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378.  Instead of asking about why your search isn't updating until a second keyup event, you are asking about your workaround, which may not even be necessary.

Comment: Well, yes and no.  Once you go down the path, it makes you wonder how to do what works.  Yes, this doesn't directly address the *problem*, but it is an interesting learning experience.

Comment: I think the answer from @PaulS would work here, but I would encourage you to consider opening a question regarding your data search (if you haven't already) as it sounds like you might have a bug that may come back to bite you later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) as a *constructor* you could do the following in *vanilla JavaScript*

```
var e = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {shiftKey: true});
node.dispatchEvent(e);
```

where `node` is the target element

---

More completely

```
function press_shift(target, /*optional*/ bubbles, /*optional*/ events) {
    var o = {shiftKey: true};
    if (bubbles) o.bubbles = true;
    if (!events && events !== 0) events = -1;
    if ((events & 1) === 1) target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', o));
    if ((events & 2) === 2) target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', o));
    if ((events & 4) === 4) target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', o));
}
press_shift.keydown = 1;
press_shift.keypress = 2;
press_shift.keyup = 4;

// and then for example, to just do a keypress which bubbles up the DOM
press_shift(document.body, true, press_shift.keypress);
```

Comment: Thanks for you last update.  I was struggling with the exact implementation.  It works!

Answer (score 0):

you can use "keydown" event instead. It will give you the result you want.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt){
   console.log(evt);
});
```